# Number of integers having property

Tags: number-theory, dynamic-programming

Find how many integers $z$ occur from $1$ to $N$ such that they have one $1s$, or two $2s$ or ... or nine $9s$.
Eg: 11232 is valid as it has two $2s$.

Comment: I don't know how this is related to dynamic programming, but this seems like a case of inclusion-exclusion principle to me, albeit more drawn out.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг We can use something like $dp(len, d, valid)$ which is the number of numbers of length len, using digits from $d,d+1...,9$ and 'valid' = 1 when there is some digit $x$ that is already occuring $x$ times, otherwise its 0. But in this way I can only find number of numbers of $N-digits$ or less satisfying the given property.

Comment: The question is unclear; in particular, it's unclear whether a number to be valid needs *exactly* n digits equal to n, or *at least* n digits equal to n. For example is 11 (which has more than 2 digits equal to 1) a valid number?